# What is the term for managing GitHub permissions per directory?

Tags: git, github

Not even sure if I asked the question right.

I have a repo for company1.com/foo which lives in directory ~/go/foo, for company foo. I have a repo for company2.com/bar which lives in directory ~/go/bar. I am hoping that when I'm working in the local repos git can look in the .git directory for completely different sets of permissions and even users.

When I'm working on the foo repo I'd like it to expect credentials for company1.com, so `git push` from ~/go/foo updates https://github.com/company1/foo with user ID `fred@company.com`. When I'm working on the bar repo from ~/go/bar, and do a `git push` it uses credentials for user ID `fredz@company2.com` and updates https://github.com/company2/bar.

I'm trying to look this up on git-scm.org but I don't know the term of art. Something like "per repo GitHub permissions" or "local git permissions" or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set `credential.useHttpPath` to True in your global Git configuration:

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

According to the [manual for git credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials):

> useHttpPath
> By default, Git does not consider the "path" component of an http URL to be worth matching via external helpers. This means that a credential stored for https://example.com/foo.git will also be used for https://example.com/bar.git. If you do want to distinguish these cases, set this option to true.

Answer (score 0):

`git config` can be specified at several levels. From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> When writing, the new value is written to the repository local configuration file by default, and options --system, --global, --worktree, --file  can be used to tell the command to write to that location (you can say --local but that is the default).

So it seems like `git config user.name "My Name"` and `git config user.email "my@email.com"` will do what you want as long as you run them in the correct directories.

Comment: OP is asking about per-repo GitHub credentials, which is not what `user.name` and `user.email` control: those are just for setting the commit author name and e-mail.